# Deleting the Ubuntu Swap Partition

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows XP.

- XP on C: drive
- Ubuntu on D: drive
- and E: linux swap

E: drive disappeared from XP "My Computer" but it appears in disk management saying unknown logical partition. if I delete it,  will free space split over the drives or will just be uninitialized?

Comment: Format your question using real sentences. I can barely make any sense out of this. What was the E: drive before you installed Ubuntu? Did you split C or E for the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: I don't understand, and you didn't answer my questions.

Comment: XP will not see the E drive because it is what it is... a linux swap. Unsupported file system, which can only be used by Ubuntu

Comment: so you want to shrink your swap partition? you can use gparted which came with Ubuntu Live CD, I am not sure if thats what you used to install Ubuntu 14x, but it might already be installed or on your install disc.

Comment: you should use gparted and shrink the linux swap partition, and format the free space with a file system that XP can use. I am not sure of the consequences of the Ubuntu install if you delete its swap partition.

Comment: If you delete the swap partition, Ubuntu will run without swap. You can create a file to use for swapping instead of a partition, but you cannot hibernate. (There are instructions for hibernating to a swap file, but it all seems a bit dodgy, as it involves finding the swap file's absolute disc address and using this in the set-up: if the swap file moves, hibernating will corrupt the file system.)

Comment: @AFH Thank you I'm using 2 GB RAM so recommended size for swap?

Comment: I don't agree with the normal _swap size_ = _RAM size_ recommendation. It depends on the number and size of applications you run at any one time. Because I do a lot, I go for ~16GB, regardless of the RAM size. You don't want ever to run out out of swap space, because the system just freezes and you can't get applications into memory to terminate them. So err on the large side. Once Ubuntu is running, you can use the `free` command to monitor swap use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return freed space was held by deleted partition you can either work from Windows with something like [**Partition Wizard**](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) or from Ubuntu with **[Gparted](http://gparted.org/)**. Returning space means resize, and often, moving the partitions. The last one is just copying itself. So be ready it may take a few hours.

Also you can run Linux's `Gparted` from Live CD of a variety linux distributions, such as Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian, OpenSuse or ever from *[Gparted Live CD](http://gparted.org/download.php)*

Answer (score 2):

> if I delete it then will those free space goes split other drives or will just uninitialized

Deleting a partition will free up the space that was held by that partition. It will not automatically add the space to any other partition. In Windows, you will see this as a black bar in Disk Management. You can create another partition from this unallocated space. Deleting the partition will delete all your data, so back up what you want to keep first.